# How to remove an index from a String Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have the following code which verifies if an item exists in an array of strings and if it does not, it will add a new item, else it will delete, but I can't find a way to delete the index if it exists.

```
TextView StudentId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idChild);
TextView SchoolId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.schoolId);
IdSchool = String.valueOf(SchoolId.getText());
IdStudents = String.valueOf(StudentId.getText());


aMap = new HashMap<String, GPSSchools>();
if (!aMap.containsKey(idSchool)) {
    mGpsSchools = new GPSSchools();
    aMap.put(idSchool, mGpsSchools);
    aMap.get(idSchool).setStudens_ids(idChild);
} else {
    String ia = aMap.get(idSchool).getStudens_ids();
    String[] iaArray = ia.split(";");
    String res = Arrays.toString(iaArray);

    if (!res.contains(IdStudents)) {
        aMap.get(IdSchool).set(ia + ";" + IdAluno);
    } else {
        ary = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        String ia = aMap.get(IdEscola).getStudens_ids();
        String[] iaArray = ia.split(";");

        ary.put(IdStudents, iaArray);

        if (!ary.containsValue(IdStudents)) {
            aMap.get(IdSchool).setStudens_ids(ia + ";" + IdStudents);
        } else {
            ary.remove(IdStudents);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class GPSEscolas  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Integer id_escola;
    private Set<String> ids_alunos;
    private double distancia;
    private Float latitude;
    private Float longitude;


    public Integer getId_escola() {
        return id_escola;
    }

    public void setId_escola(Integer id_escola) {
        this.id_escola = id_escola;
    }

    public Set<String> getStudens_ids() {
    return Studens_ids;
    }

    public void setStudens_ids(Set<String> studens_ids) {
    Studens_ids = studens_ids;
    }

    public double getDistancia() {
        return distancia;
    }

    public void setDistancia(double distancia) {
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }

    public Float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: `res` is a string not string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and nicest would be to make `getIds_alunos()` a `Set<String>`.

Otherwise forget also about using a string array. As split uses a regex, just keep using regular expressions immediately:

```
mGpsEscolas = aMap.get(IdEscola).getIds_alunos();
if (mGpsEscolas == null) {
    mGpsEscolas = new GPSEscolas();
    aMap.put(IdEscola, mGpsEscolas);
    mGpsEscolas.setIds_alunos(IdAluno);
} else {
    String ia = mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos();
    if (!ia.matches(ia, "(.*;)?" + IdAluno + "(;.*)?")) {
        ia += ";" + IdAluno;
    } else {
        //Remove IdEscola if exists.
        ia = ia.replaceFirst(";" + idAluno + "((;.*)?)$", "$1");
    }
    mGpsEscolas.setIds_alunos(ia);
}
```

As `Set<String>`:

The field with student ids can be immediately usable:

```
private Set<String> ids_alunos = new TreeSet<>();

mGpsEscolas = aMap.get(IdEscola);
if (mGpsEscolas == null) {
    mGpsEscolas = new GPSEscolas();
    aMap.put(IdEscola, mGpsEscolas);
    mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos().add(IdAluno);
} else {
    Set<String> ia = mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos();
    if (!ia.contains(IdAluno)) {
        ia.add(IdAluno);
    } else {
        //Remove IdEscola if exists.
        ia.remove(idAluno);
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
    if (!ia.remove(IdAluno)) {
        ia.add(IdAluno);
    }
```

This should work. The getter `getIds_alunos()` gives access to the actual field's set (not a copy). Hence you can add/remove on the field itself.

Comment: Set<String> ia = mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos(); gives an error of incompatible types

Comment: Yes, the field in GPSEscolas then should be changed to something like `private Set<String> alunos = new TreeSet<>();`.

Comment: But that is the model, I need to use the GPSEscolas

Comment: Then you can only use the String code; the first part?

Comment: I'm not understanding it, the second way would be perfect to me, but can't make it work

Comment: I had a getter to many, corrected. I am having some difficulty  understanding the non-English names.

Comment: I've edited the question, see if you can understand now

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#removeElement(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) has a method for this:

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from the specified array. All subsequent elements are shifted to the left (substracts one from their indices). If the array doesn't contains such an element, no elements are removed from the array.

```
iaArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(iaArray, element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the length of an array, but there are several workaround:

1. `System.arraycopy(a, del + 1, a, del, a.length - 1 - del)`, and set the last item to `null`.
2. Instead of using `array`, try to use `ArrayList`